# Get the the type of the class of a generic type?

Tags: java, generics

A class which has a method declared as this:

```
public class A{
    public <T> T test(java.lang.Class<T> classOfT)
}
```

Normally it can be called against an object like this:

```
A a = new A()
String s = "test";
a.test(String.class); //I wrote this as s.class at first,which is wrong.Thanks Nick.
```

Now I would like to generalize the object passed to it, so I declare a class like this:

```
public class B <T>{
    private A a   = new A();
    private T obj = null;
    T test(){return a.test(obj.getClass()); } 
}
```

But the code wont' compile.I am wondering is it possible to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance Java gurus ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T obj = ...;
obj.getClass()
```

The last line returns `Class<? extends T>` -- but `T` is unbounded, so it is basically bounded by `Object`, which means it returns `Class<? extends Object>`, which is the same as `Class<?>`.

So doing this:

```
T test () { return a.test(obj.getClass()); }
```

Will actually invoke `a.test` with a parameter of type `Class<?>`, which returns an `Object`, and not a `T`.

Just cast the parameter to `Class<T>` or the return type to `T` and it should work -- although I am yet to understand why you need something like this. Also, there is this strange error in the original post:

```
 String s = "test";
 a.test(s.class);
```

Doing `"test".class` is wrong -- it should be `String.class`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class<T> clazz  = (Class<T>) obj.getClass();
return a.test(clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T test() {
    return (T) a.test(obj.getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement of the other answers, when defining your function as

```
public class A{
    public <T> T test(java.lang.Class<T> classOfT) { ... }
}
```

if you are using the `classOfT` parameter just to determine the type of `T`, you might be better off defining your method with no parameter at all. For instance, do this instead of the above declaration :

```
public class A{
    public <T> T test() { ... }
}
```

That way you can just call it using this qualified method-call syntax. This is how I would rewrite your code:

```
public class A{
    public <T> T test() {
          // ...
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          A a = new A();
          String result = a.<String>test(); 
    }
}

public class B <T> {
    private A a = new A();

    T test() {
        return this.a.<T>test();
    }
}
```

This way you do not need to pass the generic `A#test()` function a class parameter, which would possibly have been unused at runtime. 
Of course if you do use the `classOfT` at runtime, this solution may not be that much interesting for you...